# laravel 5.4 eloquent model loading , porting from 4.1 project

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-5.4

I am currently porting an old site using laravel 4.1 to laravel 5.4. Already implemented a lot of minor changes (error logs helps) but I am stuck with the following model usage:

```
namespace App;


class navire extends Eloquent
{
protected $table = 'navire';

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('user');
}

public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

}
```

I m trying to call it from a controller :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

use App\navire;

class UserController extends Controller
{
   public function somefunc()
   {
      // .... 

      $navire = \navire::where('user_id',$user->id)->get()->take(1);


    }

}
```

Tried many thing using "use ..." or calling it with a \ at beginning , nothing has worked so far

exemples of errors :

```
local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'App\Http\Controllers\navire' not found' in /home/user/www/app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php:30

local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'App\Http\Controllers\navire' not found' in /home/user/www/app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php:30

local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'App\navire' not found' in /home/user/www/app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php:32

 local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'navire' not found' in /home/user/www/app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php:32
```

I already called dumpautoload.

Comment: Remove \ from the class when you are calling it

Comment: @LeaTano without the use App\navire : 'Class 'App\Http\Controllers\navire' not found , with :  'Class 'App\Eloquent' not found'

Comment: class navire extends \Eloquent fixes the issue. thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either use `$navire = \App\navire::where('user_id',$user->id)->get()->take(1);`
or as you have already imported the model use `$navire = navire::where('user_id',$user->id)->get()->take(1);` i.e. with out the slash in front.

Another thing, you can just use `first()` instead of `->get()->take(1)`. Like this `$navire = \App\navire::where('user_id',$user->id)->first();`

Comment: using directly navire::where leads to message 'Class 'App\navire' not found' error.

Comment: @NicoAD did you include use App\navire?

Comment: now I get message 'Class 'Authenticatable' not found'. each time I fix an issue I m getting a new one. I remember that what I liked first in laravel 4 what the clean & elegant solution for autoload. now with 5.4 it s a mess..